# Why is an Imperial hundredweight not a hundred of anything?

Tags: etymology

An imperial hundredweight is a measure weighing eight stone, or 112 pounds, or 1792 ounces.  Why isn't it a hundred of anything?

Comment: Maybe it was a hundred of something.

Comment: The Hundred Years' War didn't last 100 years, and a kilobyte is 1024 bytes. Sometimes, we round for simplicity.

Comment: Plus, the Empire is gone, so its old standards have not been enforced.

Comment: Possibly related to the old geographical division known as a 'hundred'?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundredweight), there are 20 hundredweight per ton. The long hundredweight is defined as 112 lb (8 stone), which is equal to 50.802345 kg. The short hundredweight is 100 lb, which is equal to 45.359237 kg.

Comment: So the metric hundredweight came first and the imperial one just took the name?

Answer (score -1):

A hudred weight is a hundred bundles of wheat. I'm not sure what a bundle was though, but in the past they probably weren't weighing them.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Where did this come from?